# Is there any info about using MS SQL Server with MediaWiki?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, mediawiki

I wonder if it possible to use mediawiki 1.18 with MS SQL server(particullary, MS SQL server 2008 r2), and, if possible, where to find some info about them working together. I know that mysql is much better solution, but our client insist on oracle DB or MS SQL. And i'd prefer MS SQL because i nether worked with oracle db and we still would have to buy it. Can somebody give me any help?
Current version of my mediawiki is 1.18

Comment: Dupe of this server fault question - http://serverfault.com/questions/88224/mediawiki-on-ms-sql-server

Comment: That looks pretty dead and is still unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9767

(i'm know that not 1.18)